# Why isn't linked editing disabled in VS Code even when I set "editor.linkedEditing": false?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to disable this feature named `Linked Editing` (formerly mirror cursor) in VS Code. I have a template copy and pasted and no chance to clean up tags and co, cause VS Code always messes with the tags.

For example:

```html
<p>Aloha from Hawaii</p>
<p>And have a nice day.</p>
```

As soon, as I start changing the type of the first opening `<p>` tag VS Code changes the closing tag as well. I want to disable this behavior, but for whatever reason I can't. I've set `"editor.linkedEditing": false` but hat didn't help.

Any Ideas, what to do?

Comment: check if the setting is overridden on a per-language basis for the language you are writing in. on that note, what language mode is this? Check the language mode indicator on the bottom right.

Comment: The setting is only set once in settings.json and not overridden. The language mode I use is HTML.

Comment: Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: Thank you starball, you were right, it was an old installed extension (Auto Rename Tag) which caused the problem. I'm very rarely using VS Code, and have a bunch of extensions running which found their way into the editor over the years. I must confess, VSC gets me almost every time some headache I use it. But this seems to meet almost every tool you use very seldom. Update required? Better go to the beach and enjoy your life... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was due to extension interference from the [`formulahendry.auto-rename-tag`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-rename-tag) extension (interfering with VS Code's builtin linked editing feature). The issue can be resolved by disabling or uninstalling the extension.